# JavaScript spread operator over a variable number of arguments?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

The JavaScript spread operator can combine arrays like this:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = [4,5,6];
console.log([...a,...b]);
```

Can I also use it when the number of arguments is unknown at "compile time"?

In the following example I didn't know how to use the spread operator so I used `reduce` and `concat`.

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b)));
```

Is this the intended way or can I use the spread operator in some way with a variable number of arguments like those?

Comment: Use `arrays.flat()` or `[].concat(...arrays)`.

Comment: Just as a side note: `...` isn't an operator. It doesn't really matter much, but that's why you can't just use it in any expression context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know how many things you're spreading, you can't write the code to spread them with `...`. It's just like `+` in that way: You can add three things together (`a + b + c`), but if you don't know how many you're adding, you can't directly write the code for it.

Your `reduce` could use spread rather than `concat` (but keep reading):

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce((a,b)=>[...a, ...b]));
```

But both that and `concat` are inefficient (which may or may not matter) because they create a **new** array and re-copy the elements that have already been copied for every input. If efficiency is a constraint, just use a simple loop:

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
const result = [];
for (const entry of arrays) {
  result.push(...entry);
}
console.log(result);
```

Or if you really like doing it in a single expression, you can shoehorn it into a `reduce` (because basically any array operation can be shoehorned into a `reduce`):

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce((acc,entry) => {
  acc.push(...entry);
  return acc;
}, []));
```

I'm with [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544), though: For me, `reduce` is overused.

In closing, for this specific issue, we're getting [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) now:

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(arrays.flat());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most concise I can think of:

```
console.log(...[].concat(...arrays));
```

The innermost spread will give all the arrays as arguments to `concat` without the need for `reduce`.

Another way is using the ES2019 `Array.prototype.flat`:

```
console.log(...arrays.flat())
```

EDIT: I just noticed you're outputting it as an array. Change to `console.log([].concat(...arrays))` and `console.log(arrays.flat())` for that :)

Comment: :-) Well, there's `arrays.flat()` now, which is more concise (externally).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.flat` instead, if you don't pass the parameter depth is considered as `1` and you can manually define depth or you can use `Infinity` to cover any depths

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(arrays.flat());
```